# Hiding google maps raw data from user

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get into the google maps api v3 to display store locations.

All non-flash tutorials for google maps, which I have seen so far, create an array with the latitude and longitude in either java script part of the html or in a seperate js file.
However, then I list all coordinates in plain text in the requested html site.

**Is there a way to hide the exact location in a seperate file or layer, which is not accessible to the user?** I would like to display the locations with a broad view and would like to keep the exact locations hidden.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if it is possible to do, but you can try create external PHP script that will returns JSON output with all Google Maps data.

In the beggining of the script you can check referer and it is correct (equals to the site script) show that data - otherwise, print some error, etc.

In JavaScript load whole data with Ajax.

However there is no way to permanently hide data from user - it is always possible to write some script that will export them from Google Map (for example using FireBug/Chrome console).